# mirror.famaserver.com Not found

Tags: server, mirrors

I got Ubuntu 20.04.3 and it tells me that I have  to download python py, but when I click on install it says:Server not found. My question:How can I change to another server-should it not do this by it self?
Many Thanks!

Comment: What says you need to download it. You need to give a lot more details.

Comment: Have you tried to get it from here? https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain what exactly it is that you want. Is it the installation of python?

Comment: It says to go on I need to install: python py-pydrive.When I click on install it says:mirror-famaserver-com-not-found?noredirect=1#comment2354607-1369795